# Using in_array with currency symbol?

Tags: php, arrays, currency, euro

I'm working on a PHP file which can echo a price (given by an array from another website) converted in a certain currency (let's say in € for example).

I thought about using the in_array function to check if the price retreived from the other webpage contains the currency character or not. Only problem: it doesn't recognize that symbol, even if I use a predefined array. If I try to change the $currency array to the actual price given by the priceclass, it will work. 
Thanks in advance!

```
$html=file_get_contents('http://thewebsite');
preg_match_all("thepriceclass", $html, $a);

foreach(end($a) as $key=> $value)
{
   print print_r($value, true).'<br>';
   $currency = array("€");
   $value = str_split($value);
   $message = "This listing =/= €";

   foreach($value as $letter)
   {
      if (in_array($letter, $currency)) 
      {
         $message = "This listing == €";
         break;
      }
   }
   echo $message;
   break;
}
```

Comment: Could be a problem with encodings.

Comment: BTW, if you want to look for a character or string in another string, use `strstr()`, you don't need to split it into an array.

Comment: try specifying the encoding as `unicode` , for example.


http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Comment: @kevin: do you mean by using their unicode value as an array?

Comment: I haven't worked with such currency symbols before. But, I think this may help you http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Answer (score 0):

How many currencies do you have? It it's not all of them, why not use ISO codes (ex. USD, EUR, JPY etc.) instead?

I would create a little function that converts symbols into code and vice versa.

### EDIT:

In the comments you said you are working with €, $, £ and pуб.

I think the problem is the encoding, either because PHP is latin1, or things like that.

I'd just use the currency code (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217). In you case: USD, EUR, GBP, RUB, and compare with that.

I don't understand your code fully, as you look for the value in the array, but the you always print €. I assume it's just for testing.

I'd do:

```
$currency = array('EUR');
```

or:

```
$currency = array('USD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'RUB');
```

If you can't use the above I'd do something like this...

```
$currencies = array('USD'=>'$', 'EUR'=> '€', 'GBP'=>'£', 'RUB'=>'pуб');
```

...and use the array values and keys to compare/print.

Would that work?

Comment: Ah, well I would definitely do that, then. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It still doesn't work even if I use the Unicode instead of the $,€,... symbol. Could this be because of the padder of the price (a dollar price is for example &#36;0.50 whereas a euro price is 0.50&#8364; for example)?

Comment: OMG... I would think so, but from your code I can't really tell what's going on.